# Wifite problem (loop when I execute)

Tags: debian, wifi, wlan

I have just installed wifite on Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). And when I execute it from Gnome-terminal started to loop prompting this:

```
enabling monitor mode on wlan0... done
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: I don't use Gnome so I can't repro, but this might be a starting point: Wifite is a [single-file Python 2.7 program](https://github.com/derv82/wifite/blob/master/wifite.py) and [line 889](https://github.com/derv82/wifite/blob/edbdedd149254f58a99d2f53e5e9b8105c4c61bb/wifite.py#L889) is responsible for printing that diagnostic. Try using a debugger or adding some `print` statements where you think it might be looping, and ask on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/derv82/wifite/issues).

Comment: Does it solves it if you do sudo service network-manager stop before?

Comment: No. It has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have multiple causes:

- Have you installed aircrack-ng?
- Does your wireless card support monitor mode? If it's your laptop's internal card, it probably doesn't. Here is a list of recommended cards https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?19387-802-11-Recommended-Wireless-Cards
- The versions of wifite and aircrack-ng do not correspond. A while ago, the aircrack-ng team rewrote the way of naming interfaces from "mon0" to "wlan0mon". You can download the latest version of aircrack-ng from hxxp://www.aircrack-ng.org/downloads.html and you can clone the latest version of wifite from the git repository at hxxps://github.com/derv82/wifite. (Can't show link because of reputation..)

Try the Kali live-cd (pre-installed correct versions of wifite and aircrack-ng) It's at https://kali.org. Use the following command "airmon-ng start wlan0". If it says "failed to bring up card using ip", your card doesn't support monitor mode.

Comment: I have installed aircrack-ng. Are you sure of he command? It return to me 'command not found'

Comment: Yup, just used it on my Kali linux machine (like debian). How did you install aircrack-ng? Does the command "aircrack-ng" work? If not, install aircrack with "apt-get install aircrack-ng"

Comment: @Icaro did it work?